# Punctuation used in the celebration of a festival. (full stop vs exclamation mark)

Tags: exclamatives

Please tell me the difference between these two example letters:
(1). 
Dear teachers,
Happy New Year!
sender's name
(2). 
Dear teachers,
Happy New Year.
sender's name
If a student used an exclamation mark with "Happy New Year", does this mean that he had a stronger desire to wish the recipent have a happy new year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing a greeting card I will always use an exclamation mark.

The exclamation mark, in your context, indicates a strong feeling such as joy that you wish to your addressee, it's like rasing your voice to express it when face to face, whereas the period shows that you merely make a statement or a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I would generally use an exclamation mark.

With the *happy* in the holiday name, if you just make it a statement (using a period) it sounds like you are not really looking forward to a *happy* year.